# How to find the specific times of entities entering a conveyor in ARENA?

Tags: simulation, arena-simulation

I am currently having trouble trying to find the actual time of all entities entering a specific conveyor belt in ARENA simulation. 
  In other words, I am trying to find the entity with the longest time spent in the specific conveyor OR to find the entity that entered the specific conveyor earliest. This is to have a "first come first serve" process. Is there a specific ARENA built in function to find the earliest entity conveying in a conveyor with the specific time, so it can be used as an expression ? Thank you